# Not able to start Weblogic services

Tags: java, windows-services, weblogic, weblogic11g, wlst

I am using Weblogic 11g, and JDK version - `jdk1.8.0_60`.

I created a domain successfully with a managed server and installed windows services for my application. But when I start my windows services it gives the below error message

[image]

I am able to start the services from the command prompt by running these batch files : startWebLogic.cmd and startManagedWebLogic.cmd for AdminServer and ManagedServer respectively.

I have not found any sort of errors in log files and also in the event viewer.

Comment: what about logs in the domain directory?

Comment: Even domain logs showed no error, but i got the solution. The JDK version I was using had compatibility issues due to an option called 'UseSpinning'. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/adminguide/winservice.html#1188201  This one was helpful.